# Date conversion in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have text file which contain data like below:

```
1000;xxx;08-09-2016 07:30;09-09-2016 10:35;yyy
1001;yyy;09-09-2016 10:36;10-10-2016 11.37;xxx
```

I want date to be converted to `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```
1000;xxx;2016-09-08 07:30;2016-09-09 10:35;yyy
1001;yyy;2016-09-09 10:36;2016-10-10 11.37;xxx
```

Comment: What is your code so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you project on Java or Scala you might use java.time library.

Example on Scala:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.{LocalDateTime, ZoneId, ZoneOffset}

val formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
val formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))

val time = "08-09-2016 07:30"

val timestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(time, formatter1).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)

val reformattedTime = formatter2.format(timestamp) // "2016-09-08 07:30"
```